# Pattern Matching with SQL Like with first part letters and second part numbers of varying length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to use Pattern Matching with SQL LIKE, to match first part of letters and a second part of variable number of numbers?

For example, I want to select only ABC1002, ABC23, ABC569, CDE48569.

Comment: Do you want ABC or 123 to be returned? I.e. are both letters and digits required?

Comment: ABC1002, ABC23, ABC569, CDE48569. are the output , so what is the input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
where col like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]%' and
      col not like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%[^0-9]%'
```

The logic says:

- The column starts with three letters and a digit.
- Nothing other than a digit follows the three letters.